# Ionic 3 show ion-item on select

Tags: angular, ionic3

i need to show the item when i slect an option but im not sure how ill do this if any one can help thanks

```
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Reward </ion-label>
        <ion-select>
                <ion-option >Price reduction</ion-option>
                <ion-option (click)="onButtonClick()" >Discount </ion-option>
            </ion-select>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item *ngIf="buttonClicked" >
        <ion-label floating>Discount Percentage </ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" ></ion-input>

    </ion-item>
```

i want when i click on discount then the ion item show other wise it will not show . its working fine on button when i apply it on ion-option its not working . Thanks in advance

Comment: Try something like `(click)="buttonClicked = true"` and in your component add `public buttonClicked: boolean;`

Comment: its working when i use (click)="buttonclicked()" on button but its not working on selector

Comment: ok then create a method `public buttonclicked() { this.buttonClicked = true; }`

Comment: not working with true also try with         this.buttonClicked = !this.buttonClicked;
not working with both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ionChange` instead, and put the function call on the `ion-select` tag, not `ion-option`. As you want to only show the div if discount is chouse, we set a value for the options and check that in the function:

```html
<ion-select (ionChange)="onButtonClick($event)">
  <ion-option value="reduction">Price reduction</ion-option>
  <ion-option value="discount">Discount</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

TS:

```ts
onButtonClick(ev) {
  ev === 'discount' ? this.buttonClicked = true : this.buttonClicked = false;
}
```

**[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-k9xdxv?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)**

Comment: Thanks bro . but i have 2 items one will open when click on price reduction and another is open on discount can you please tell how  ionchange will work on 2 items ?

Comment: Yeah, I realized that when I took a closer look, check updated answer :)

Comment: when i click on reduction its also open the discount item .  i add other line ev === 'reduction' ? this.buttonClicked2 = true : this.buttonClicked2 = false; like this

Comment: i have two ion-items . i need when i click on discount the discount iem show and if i click on reduction the reduction item show . if possible for you please update thanks

Comment: Well you have not presented that in your question! But the idea is the same, you just then open another div when reduction is chosen. Use two boolean flags and `if else`.

Comment: Great, glad to hear! :) Have a nice day and happy coding! :)